# Moving a QScopedPointer to Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, opencv, image-processing

The last weeks I read a lot about RAII and thought that I should start using smart pointers in my applications. As an example I tried to modify one of my applications. It captures frames from a webcam in a thread, performes image processing in another thread and displays the processed and unprocessed images in QT widgets. One central Object is the CCameraHandler which controls the capturing thread and image processing thread. Up to this point I used 4 plain pointers as members in this class:

```
CCameraCapture* m_CameraCapture;
CImageProcessor* m_ImageProcessor;
QThread* m_CameraCaptureThread;
QThread* m_ProcessingThread;
```

In the constructor of CCameraHandler I created the Instances using new and moved the capture object to the thread:

```
m_CameraCaptureThread= new QThread();
m_CameraCapture= new CCameraCapture();
//Move camera capture object to thread
m_CameraCapture->moveToThread(m_CameraCaptureThread);
```

That approach worked nicely. Now I wanted to a first test with QScopedPointer and tried to change m_CameraCapture to a QScopedPointer using

```
QScopedPointer<CCameraCapture> m_CameraCapture;
```

and initializing it with CameraCapture(new CCameraCapture()) in the initialization list. It compiled nicely and works as it should but when I close the application an the destructors are called I get an error from Qt:"Cannot send events to objects owned by a different thread. Current thread 5ff590. Receiver '' (of type 'CCameraCapture') was created in thread 4b7780" I guess that it has to do with the m_CameraCapture->moveToThread(m_CameraCaptureThread); where I now move a scoped pointer. Is the QScopedPointer automatically parented by CCameraCapture? So far I used

```
//This connections guarantees that the m_CCameraCapture and m_CameraCapture are deleted after calling QThread::exit()
QObject::connect(m_CameraCaptureThread, SIGNAL(finished()), m_CameraCaptureThread, SLOT(deleteLater()));
QObject::connect(m_CameraCaptureThread, SIGNAL(finished()), m_CameraCapture, SLOT(deleteLater()));
```

to delete thread an worker when camera capturing is stopped. If m_CameraCapture is now parented by CCameraHandler that might cause the problems. At the moment I am not so sure if it is a good Idea to use a SmartPointer in this case. Any Ideas what might cause this error on destruction?

Edit:
The CCameraHandler dtor looks like this (threads should be deleted before the worker):

```
CCameraHandler::~CCameraHandler(void)
{
//Stop grabbing and processing
emit stopGrabbing();
emit stopProcessing();
/*Wait for the capture thread to terminate. The destructor of CCamera Handler might be called on application close. Therefore it is important to wait for QThreads to terminate. Else the application might close before threads get deleted*/
m_CameraCaptureThread->exit();
m_CameraCaptureThread->wait();
//Wait for the processing thread to terminate
m_ProcessingThread->exit();
m_CameraCaptureThread->wait();
qDebug() << "CCameraHandler deleted";
}
```

Comment: Do you still get the errors if you explicitly specify Qt::QueuedConnection in the connect calls?

Comment: QScopedPointer is not related to Qt thread managment. It is not a QObject.

Comment: Thanks for the hint that it is not a QObject. I will check if explicitly specifying a QueuedConnection will change anything - although I think nothing will change because I set the connections after moving the worker to the thread. Therefore, a queued connection should be chosen by Qt.

Answer (score 1):

An object that has been moved to another thread must be destructed either:

1. From the thread itself, or
2. From any thread *after* the thread itself has been destructed.

Caveat: `QThread` is not safe to be destructed before you stop it. To do that safely to a thread that merely runs an event loop, you should use the following subclass instead:

```
class Thread : public QThread {
  using QThread::run; // final
public:
  Thread(QObject * parent = 0) : QThread(parent) {}
  ~Thread() { quit(); wait(); }
};
```

Given such a class, destructed from the GUI thread, you simply need to destruct it before you destruct any objects that were moved to the thread. Of course, it's not necessary to hold such objects as pointers at all, but the code below will work whether you hold them directly or as pointers.

```
class Foo : public Bar {
  CCameraCapture m_CameraCapture;
  CImageProcessor m_ImageProcessor;
  Thread m_CameraCaptureThread;
  Thread m_ProcessingThread;
  ...
}
```

When the class is destructed, the following happens, in order:

1. `~Foo()` body runs (it may be empty).
2. Members in the `...` section, if any, are destructed in reverse order of declaration.
3. `m_ProcessingThread.~Thread` runs, followed by superclass destructors (~QThread, and finally ~QObject). Any objects that were moved to that thread are now threadless.
4. `m_CameraCaptureThread.~Thread` runs, followed by superclass destructors. Any objects that were moved to that thread are now threadless.
5. `m_ImageProcessor` destructors run. As a threadless object, the destruction is safe from any thread.
6. `m_CameraCapture` destructors run. As a threadless object, the destruction is safe from any thread.

If you used `QScopedPointer<...>` to hold those instances, things would be exactly the same, just that every object's destruction would be wrapped in the body of `~QScopedPointer<...>`.

Note that the use of even a raw pointer to hold those instances is a premature pessimization: you waste a bit of heap, and access to the instances is a bit slower due to an extra layer of indirection. Those things in isolation may not play a big role, but if there are thousands of objects all coded that way, things can add up.

Don't allocate class members in individual heap blocks unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I usually prefer not to construct members on the heap but as I am new to Qt I saw all these examples where they seem to construct everything on the heap. Also connect seems to be made for pointers so I decided to follow that approach. Back to the main question: I added the code of the CCameraHandler dtor above to show that threads are stopped before the worker ist deleted. Without QScopedPointer everything works fine (I have an qdebug output in every dtor and can follow the destruction order).

Comment: `QObject::connect` is not made for pointers, it simply accepts pointers to objects as arguments :) When reading code examples, it helps to keep in mind that it's still C++, and just because it uses Qt doesn't mean you should accept gratuituously inefficient C++ :)

Answer (score 1):

If you need moveToThread with QScopedPointer example look [here](https://github.com/AndreiCherniaev/QThread-with-moveToThread_console).

Comment: Don't post links to code, as URLs tend to rot and become out of date. Instead, quote the relevant code in the answer itself to improve both readability and for SEO sake.

Comment: Usually no way to write all code. And part of the code is not interesting. Interesting all project itself.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that you are doing some UI stuff from none UI thread.
It is hard to tell exactly where is the problem since you didn't give information what exacly CCameraCapture do.

I suspect that after capturing a frame you are setting a pixmap on label (to show frame) instead emit a signal with new frame and connect this signal with respective slot of UI element. So I think that scoped pointer and signal and slots have nothing to do with your problem, problem is that you didn't use signal slot mechanism in place where it was required.

Comment: A I wrote above "That approach worked nicely.". So everything worked before I changed to the QScopedPointer. But to answer your question: Only slots/signals are used to communicate with threads in the application. With QSscopedPointer still everything works while running with the difference that on destruction I get an error.